# Binary variables (features) used in a classification model - data visualisation

Tags: r, random-forest

I suppose this is less of a coding question but more of a plea for advice from experienced data scientists:

Suppose I have a classification problem at hand with 15 features (variables), all those variables are binary type - `1|0`. Naturally, the output is also `1|0`

I'm looking for a best / most widely used method of presenting and visualizing the output from the test data.

In the case the context might be helpful, the model is supposed to predict whether loan applicants will default on their payments after some period of time, if they're `employed|unemployed` had more than `x` days delinquency etc.
The model is `randomForest`

Comment: Usually you will display your results in a confusion matrix that shows how much of the data was correctly classified a a True Positive or True Negative, as well as how much was Not as number of False Positive and False Negatives, From there you can compute quite a few statistics on your results. You can also draw a ROC (Receiver Operating Characteristic) Curve, it shows the rate of TP to FP at different accepting thresholds. It can give you an idea if your classifier is doing good.

Comment: As per Rob use a confusion matrix, here is a useful link: http://www.dataschool.io/simple-guide-to-confusion-matrix-terminology/